# I am trying to use the grep command in linux. how to grep similar words and phrases

Tags: linux, grep

How can I grep all lines starting by a specific letter (for instance "n")in a file ?
 for the file /var/log/messages, I tried

```
# cat /var/log/messages | grep n*
```

it didn't work

Comment: `grep n*` - in that, since it's not quoted, your shell will expand the `n*` to all filenames starting with an n. If it gets to `grep` unchanged, it would match all lines with 0 or more n's in them - so every single line.

Answer (score 1):

All lines starting with `n`:

```
cat /var/log/messages | grep "^n"
```

Answer (score 1):

use regular expressions for pattern

^ Indicates the beginning of an input string

$ Indicates the end of an input string

cat /var/log/messages | grep ^n

Have a look at https://www.linux.com/topic/desktop/introduction-regular-expressions-new-linux-users/